# Loop video to audio without increasing it's file size

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

Does any modern codec/container support looping video for certain amount of time/cycles?

What I'm trying to achieve, is I have a small 15 second video file and a 3 minute audio file, and I want to loop video while audio is playing, but without encoding the video over and over.

Making something similar to what you can see https://coub.com site, but just using some native codec/container technique, as that websites stores the gif and mp3 separately.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c copy -shortest output.mp4
```

`-stream_loop -1` will make video repeat.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question, as this method will cause the filesize to increase dramatically. The question specifically asks for a method that doesn't repeatedly increase the filesize for each loop of the video.

Comment: @CrazySqueak , he said "without encoding the video repeatedly." Please check again. For the problem in question, `-stream_loop -1` solves it perfectly.